# 410 error when using website validator

Tags: http, ping, website

I am trying to ping my website http://www.saranshsingh.com/ and it fails

PING http://www.saranshsingh.com/ (198.105.254.228): 56 data bytes Request timeout for icmp_seq 0 Request timeout for icmp_seq 1 Request timeout for icmp_seq 2

but when I ping saranshsingh.com it works

and when I checked with websites validator they give me 410 gone error, google search also gives me older result but as one can see the website is live with new data

What is it that I'm missing out here?

Comment: Both addresses work for me.

Comment: that's weird because I just checked again and it failed for me

Comment: Both addresses resolve to 198.58.93.28, which responds to pings.

Comment: oh and can you help me with the 410 error code that is being displayed?